# Elided Compound or Simple sentence

Tags: descriptive-grammar

In the example

1. "He gave Tom a cycle and Jack a bike"

Is this a simple sentence or an elided (stripping) compound sentence which can be expanded to “He gave Tom a cycle and he gave Jack a bike.” Similarly, in the example:

2. "He will do it on Monday and not Tuesday"

Will this be classified as a simple sentence or an elided compound (Not-stripping ellipsis) to expand to “He will do it on Monday and he will not do it on Tuesday.”

Comment: What's the difference between a cycle and a bike?

Comment: These are simple sentences with compound direct/indirect objects and objects of a preposition.

Comment: Aren't you trying to use Newtonian physics to describe nuclear fission?

Comment: I'd treat them as layered coordinations constructions. I think this is much better than saying we have a coordination of VPs (or clauses), with ellipsis within the second coordinate.

Comment: For example, I'd analyse your first sentence as "He gave [Tom a cycle] [and Jack a bike]", where the  bracketed expressions are constituents, NPs, with no ellipsis.

Comment: Thanks Bill,  How will you interpret the second sentence?

Comment: The same. A coordination of two noun phrases, and no ellipsis.

Comment: *He gave Tom a cycle and Jack a bike* is a simple sentence because it has one subject and one predicate — no dependent clauses. In the predicate, *Tom a cycle and Jack a bike* seems to be a compound indirect/direct object. For comparison, here is a compound indirect object: *He gave Tom and Jack a bike.* And here is a compound direct object: *He gave Tom a cycle and a bike.*

Answer (score 1):

Above is a tree of your first example:
[image]

Your second example would be analysed the same way, with the coordinates being the two NPs "Monday" and "not Tuesday", serving as complement of the prep "on".

I think this is much better than saying we have a coordination of VPs (or clauses), with ellipsis within the second coordinate.

Comment: Thanks Bill for an elaborate answer. Grateful.  If you could educate me as to "In what type of sentence/clause ,ellipsis is grammatically acceptable" ?

Answer (score -1):

> "He gave Tom a cycle and Jack a bike"

cycle = bicycle

bike = bicycle

[He gave Tom a rabbit]......and.........[..Jack a bike..]

[....main clause 1........] conjunction [main clause 2 ]

Clause 2 is missing its subject and verb, nevertheless they are implied: hence elision.

*"He will do it on Monday and not Tuesday"* =

"He will do it on Monday and not[, as previously stated/believed, on] Tuesday"

*"on Monday and not[, as previously stated/believed, on] Tuesday"* is a compound adverbial phrase, with *and not[, as previously stated/believed, on] Tuesday* being parenthetical.

Compare this with 
"He will do it on Monday **but** not Tuesday" = "He will do it on Monday **but** he will not do it on Tuesday."

Comment: OP is asking whether the elided sentence should as written be regarded as being simple or compound, not say 'ex-compound'.

Comment: Yes Edwin,  That is the sense of my asking. I read on Wikipedia (linguistics)  about  Ellipsis and that's why the doubt.